# JavaScript unit tests in a separate project when using Chutzpah testrunner and requirejs in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, requirejs, jasmine, chutzpah

I'd like my tests to be in a separated project from the code under test as described in [Jasmine in a separate test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526209/jasmine-in-a-separate-test-project). However, the approach with including reference paths in the test files doesn't apply to when the test is used with requirejs. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the [chutzpah.json](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File) file settings. Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/RequireJS/CustomBaseUrlAndCustomHarnessLocation) which shows having the source and tests in different folders.

Comment: Btw, if the JS module under test has dependencies to e.g. Knockout, Underscore etc. must these dependent files be located in the same folder as the JS file containing the module being tested?